# How to not return rows

Tags: mysql, laravel, rows

I'm asking this without code because I want to know a lot of ways of how to **NOT** return rows? What I'm now using is just not so neat. What i'm now using is '1=2' which allways returns in no rows.

So what i'm asking is a nice and neat way on how to NOT return rows in an sql statement.

**UPDATE:**

```
$sql = 'SELECT `a`.`id`, 
                   `a`.`action_id`, 
                   DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(a.`time`), "%d-%m-%Y") as `date`,
                   DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(a.`time`), "%H:%i") as `time`,
                   `a`.`amount_other_callers`, 
                   `a`.`additional_data_incident`, 
                   `a`.`additional_data_result`, 
                   `a`.`additional_data_messagequality_start`, 
                   `a`.`additional_data_messagequality_end`, 
                   `a`.`additional_data_smsquality_start`, 
                   `g`.`name` AS gemeente
        FROM `actions` a
        INNER JOIN actions_geo_communities AS ac
            ON ac.lnk_action_id = a.id
        INNER JOIN geodata_communities g
            ON ac.lnk_community_id = g.id ';
    if(Auth::user()->unit_id > 0) {
        $sql.= '    INNER JOIN actions_geo_units AS au
                        ON au.lnk_action_id = a.id ';
    }
    if(Session::get('tk') === "1" && Session::get('ntk') === "1")
    {
        $sql.= '    WHERE `a`.`aangevuld` = 0 AND `a`.time > 1388530800'; 
    }
    else if (Session::get('tk') == 1)
    {
        $sql.= '    WHERE `a`.`aangevuld` = 0 AND `a`.`tk` = 1 AND `a`.time > 1388530800';
    }
    else if (Session::get('ntk') == 1)
    {
        $sql.= '    WHERE `a`.`aangevuld` = 0 AND `a`.`tk` = 0 AND `a`.time > 1388530800';
    }
    else
    {
        $sql.= '    WHERE 1=2';
    }
    if(Auth::user()->unit_id > 0) {
        $sql.= ' AND `au`.`lnk_unit_id` = ' . Auth::user()->unit_id . ' ';
    }       
    if(!empty($not_arr)) {
        $sql.= ' AND `a`.`id` NOT IN (' . implode(',', $not_arr) . ') ';
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: The most efficient way to not retrieve rows is to not run a query.

Comment: @RagingBull I would like not to put an example here because there must be a generic way.

Comment: @user3398922: We would like to know in which case you want to do so.

Comment: @RagingBull I have two checkboxes which are used as a filter. One of them must be checked or both can be checked. Depending on which one is checked (or both offcourse) I add something to my query. So in the case when they are both not selected it must return 0 rows.

Comment: The query structure or the table structure? It's a query about 3 tables

Comment: Checkboxes tipically have associated values, and translate to SQL constraints ```X IN (val1, val2, ...)```. In that case you would always want to write a function that translates the value array to an SQL condition; that function should transform the empty array either into SQL ```FALSE``` or ```X IN (-1)``` where -1 is an extremal value (that never generates a hit) but is of the expected type.

Comment: @RagingBull I've added the query. The tables would be a bit to much because they are quite large.

Comment: @LeventePánczél -1 is something similar as 1=2 because 1 can never be like 2

Comment: @user3398922 Right, but note that in this case -1 is used as a non-existing item and not as the logical expression "1=2". E.g. if you have a display_types enumeration of (1=CRT, 2=TFT, 3=Touchscreen, 4=Holodeck) then you could use ```display_type IN (...)```, so when TFT and Touchscreen are checked, the "..." in SQL will be ```2,3``` and when none is checked then "..."=-1 ensures that no rows are selected (-1 is not used, and cannot be confused with an uninitialized NULL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best answer for this is not run query , you didn't need any data so why you stress your database

In **your case** check if two or one check box is checked first then run your query otherwise don't run it at all

Answer (score 1):

I've had this case when a module needed to augment the SQL that other modules have assembled. Based on what I knew in advance about the structure of incoming SQL-parts, I did one of these: when I just had a WHERE condition I transformed it to `FALSE AND (<original_where)` or simply FALSE if it did not break the other modules. In other cases (when complex queries had multiple WHERE clauses and other clauses after WHERE) I had the luck that the system did not use LIMITs, so I was free to append `LIMIT 0`